# Изменить ключ в QMap

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть QMap формата

```
    QMap<int, QString> a;
```

где int - это номер строки в таблице.

Если я удаляю строку в таблице, соответственно, мне нужно изменить ключи в QMap:  удалить текущий и сделать декремент у тех ключей, что ниже удаленного.  Как лучше это сделать?

```
    a.remove(table->currentRow());
    for (j = a.begin(); j != a.end(); j++) {
          if (j.key() > table->currentRow()) {
                    //сделать -1 у ключа
          }
    }
```

Я вот так это представляю, но как это лучше сделать?

Comment: `сделать -1 у тех ключей` - *ключей* - множественное число. Вы действительно хотите сделать несколько элементов с одинаковым ключом? В `QMap` это невозможно, вам тогда нужен `QMultiMap`. Ни тот, ни другой класс не содержит функций для изменения ключа, поэтому для вашей задачи нужно сначала удалить элемент, а затем создать новый с ключом -1 и требуемым значением.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, товарищ хочет уменьшать на 1 значения ключа у всех строк, расположенных ниже удаленной. На мой взгляд для этого нужно пройти в цикле по всем ключам нижележащих строк и присвоить им значение на строку ниже. Если я правильно понимаю, то такой код написать несложно.

Comment: Вообще, для хранения данных, предназначенных для отображения в таблице, лучше освоить [модели](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: Как это отменяет необходимость хранения и редактирования данных?

Comment: @EugenyShtanov, никак не отменяет. Но способ хранения в этом случае может быть пересмотрен, так как в концепции моделей есть свои индексы, и не может быть такого, что несколько строк имеют индекс `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Плюсую к комментарию к вопросу - значения в `QMap` с одинаковыми ключами быть не могут. На сколько я понимаю дальше значение `-1` у вас будет где-то проверяться. Могу предложить устанавливать ключи не в `-1` а менять их знак.

```
QMap<int, QString> a;
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     a.insert(i,QString("Value_%1").arg(i));
 qDebug()<<"initial map: "<<a;

 int row=5;
 foreach (int key, a.keys())
     if(key>=row){
         a.insert(-1*key,a.value(key));
         a.remove(key);
     }
 qDebug()<<"processed map: "<<a;
```

В выводе будем иметь

> initial map:  QMap((0, "Value_0")(1, "Value_1")(2, "Value_2")(3,"Value_3")(4, "Value_4")(5, "Value_5")(6, "Value_6")(7, "Value_7")(8,"Value_8")(9, "Value_9"))

> processed map:  QMap((-9, "Value_9")(-8, "Value_8")(-7, "Value_7")(-6, "Value_6")(-5, "Value_5")(0, "Value_0")(1, "Value_1")(2, "Value_2")(3, "Value_3")(4, "Value_4"))

(Обратите внимание на реализацию цилкла перебора ключей. В таком виде код будет выглядеть более опрятно)

Comment: Я думаю, автор вопроса имел в виду декремент на -1 всех индексов строк, лежащих ниже удаленной.